# how to send my form data to java from javascript

Tags: java, javascript

In my applicaton , I have a signup form .I have a problem with saving my data in back end. Am not familiar with back end part. Am using Netbeans7.0 as my IDE and MySql 5.6 for saving my data. I dont know how to pass my data to my DB in JAVA. please help..

Comment: [What-Have-You-Tried.Com](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: which framework are you using for UI , like Struts, SpringMVC or JSP/Servlets?

Comment: You title is asking about sending data from JavaScript to Java. The body of your question is asking about sending data from Java to MySQL. What is your actual problem? Show us the code you have so far. What are you even trying to achieve (the mention of JavaScript suggestions Ajax, but doesn't confirm it)?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are have tagged javascript, I suppose, you are validating the form data using javascript. With that assumption; I think, you would have a submit button to post the data.

Now check for the following line in XSL/HTML/JSP:

```
action="{put your servlet's mapping address here}"
```

and you can submit a form in javascript using:

```
document.getElementById("frm1").submit();
```

Here is an [example](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_form_submit.asp)